# How to update x and y data arrays in a matplotlib scatter plot without using animation?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I will plot hundreds of dots and recalculate the data using a slider. I want to load the sizes of each individual dot from the array `sizes`, but `plt.plot` does not allow for a markersize array, they all must be the same.

The data set is large so I don't want to loop through each point and plot it separately, so I thought I would use `bob = plt.scatter(x, y, s=sizes)`.

I think I can use `bob.set_sizes(sizes)` to update the sizes, but now I can't figure out how to update `x` and `y`.

**Question:** How can I update the x and y data arrays in a matplotlib scatter plot **without implementing animation?**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = np.cos(10*x)
sizes  = 10*(x + y**2)

l, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ok') #s=sizes

plt.axis([-0.1, 1.1, -1.1, 1.1])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'

ax_slider  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.10, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
N_slider   = Slider(ax_slider, 'N', 5,  50, valinit=10,   valstep=1)

def update(val):
    N = int(N_slider.val)
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
    y = np.cos(10*x)
    sizes  = 10*(x + y**2)
    l.set_xdata(x)
    l.set_ydata(y)
    # l.set_s(sizes) no such thing
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

N_slider.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Also there is [an example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/rain.html#) in the matplotlib documentation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest those answers don't cover sliders. I don't want to get involved in an animation. Are you sure there is no way to update the scatter plot data without resorting to an animation?

Comment: There is no essential difference between the updating function called by a Slider and the one called by an animation, right? So why would this not be answered by any of the two duplicates?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  what does "right?" mean? If that's true, then please assert it rather than asking me! But in the mean time I ask again are you sure there is no way to update the scatter plot data without resorting to an animation? Because that's the question that I have asked here.

Comment: You are asking how to change the properties of `bob`, which, in the other answers is called `scat` or `sc`. You do by no means need a `FuncAnimation`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see `bob.set_offsets()` but I don't see how that can be used to change both the x and the y data. And with the instaclose, nobody will be able to post an answer telling me how.

Comment: You are trying very hard not to spend time on understanding the answers. In the duplicate x and y *are* changed, so it's directly applicable. There is no need for the same answer here again, and yes, duplicates are meant to prevent duplicate answers.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest okay, `bob.set_offsets(xy.T)` where `xy.T` is Nx2 does indeed work. I saw the animation-based answers and got scared. Thanks!

Comment: ```set_offsets[new_x, new_y]``` doesnt seem to work for my code. It just returns a blank canvas on my end. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @w41g87 I can't help much based on so little information, you can consider asking a new question. However try some standard steps - find the minimal script that reproduces your problem, double check that there's nothing wrong with your new_x, new_y (are they out of range of the limits of the axes - I don't think set_offsets will change the axes limits, they'll remain fixed) are there any other problems with them?

Comment: @w41g87 Once you have your [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with valid new_x, new_y post the full script a new question. You are welcome to ping me here with a link to it and I'll take a look as soon as I can.